# How to give multiples data in Kendo Treeview template

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

i am new to kendo UI i want to add id for kendo tree view elements with help of template. Here

```
$("#tree-view").kendoTreeView({
    loadOnDemand:false,
    dataSource: LOB,
    dragAndDrop:true,
    dataTextField: ["Name","NAME","Name"],
    template:"<span id='#=item.Id#' >#=item.Name#</span> " ,
```

it return only the "Name" id's. it was unable to give "NAME" dataTextfield id's.could anyone help me out.

Thank you.

Comment: What does your data source look like? Can you create a DOJ/CodePen that reproduces the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [dojo page](https://dojo.telerik.com/@zdravkov/aTUMOrEV) where a similar scenario is behaving correctly.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out.

Comment: It would be nice to vote for the answer if it helped you :)